# Laravel 4 : Where to put model helper methods?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Where is the best place to put helper methods for Laravel Eloquent models?

At the moment I'm creating a `BaseModel` that extends `Eloquent` and putting extra functionality in there. Then all my models extend `BaseModel`. It works.. but it doesn't feel right.

For Example is my BaseModel at the moment...

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

protected static function getEnumValues($table, $field)
{

    $test=DB::select(DB::raw("show columns from {$table} where field = '{$field}'"));

    preg_match('/^enum\((.*)\)$/', $test[0]->Type, $matches);
    foreach( explode(',', $matches[1]) as $value )
    {
        $enum[] = trim( $value, "'" );
    }

    return $enum;
}

protected static function convertDate($date)
{
    if(!isset($date)) return;
    $new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    $formated_date = $new_date->format('Y-m-d');
    return $formated_date;
}

}
```

And I use them in my models like...

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($campaign)
        {
            $campaign->sale_date = static::convertDate($campaign->sale_date);
            $campaign->sold_date = static::convertDate($campaign->sold_date);
        });
    }
```

Where is the best place to put model helper methods like this?

Feedback appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a static helper class then call it from your model.
You can refer to [my blog post](http://phpartisan.tumblr.com/post/71932049693/laravel-4-custom-class-best-practice) about how to add custom class. Or you can always utilize composer autoload using psr-0 or psr-4

Comment: Thanks man, just had a quick look at the post.. I'm already doing what you suggest there by adding a 'libraries' folder and putting helper methods in there. But... I ready somewhere that doing it that way is only for view helper methods although you're right... I can't see why I can't make a modelhelpers class! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I did is...I created a Helper Directory in and inside that I created a GlobalHelper.php File.

```
        app/Helper/GlobalHelper.php
```

In GlobalHelper.php

```
    namespace App\Helper;
    use App\Command;

    class GlobalHelper{
         public static function getCommands(){
              $getCommands = Command::all();
              return $getCommands;                        
       }
   }
```

Than in controller or anywhere call like this:

```
     use App\Helper\GlobalHelper;

     $getCommands = GlobalHelper::getCommands();
```